# C++ auto_ptr in functions (as argument and return value)

Tags: c++, auto-ptr

I am trying to use the auto_ptr in my code, but apparently something goes wrong.

```
auto_ptr<ClassType> Class(s.Build(aFilename)); //Instantiation of the Class object
int vM = s.GetM(Class);
int vS = s.Draw(Class);
```

The strange thing is that after the instantiation of Class, the Class object exist and so
by calling s.GetModelMean(Class), Class is not empty. But after exiting the function GetM,
Class is empty and so not usable anymore. A crash occurs when calling the function Draw.

I declared the functions the following way:

```
int GetM(auto_ptr<ClassType> aM);
```

It seems that the class is destroyed, but I do not understand why...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shout not give an auto_ptr as an argument to a function. Either do:

```
int GetM(const auto_ptr<ClassType>&)
```

or

```
int GetM(ClassType&)
```

or

```
int GetM(ClassType*)
```

(may be also with const - depends what you are doing with it). The first you would call the same way, the second function you would call like this:

```
int vM = s.GetM(*Class.get())
```

the last without the star.

The reason is: GetM will copy the auto_ptr (not the Class object) and destroy the auto_ptr when it returns. The auto_ptr (which is a scope pointer or unique pointer - not a reference counter!) will than destroy Class.

Anyway: auto_ptr is very broken. Whenever possible (your compiler already supports some small parts of C++11), use std::unique_ptr and std::shared_ptr (last one does reference counting). unique_ptr will not allow you to mess around with it like that (since copying it is not allowed - which imho makes much more sense).

Comment: Thanks, it worked even without using *Class.get(), I just passed Class and it worked.

Comment: I disagree that `auto_ptr` is very broken - I believe it just has a misleading name so the expectation of what it does is broken.

Comment: When copying auto_ptr the original is set to zero, so only single auto_ptr object controls the pointer at a time. This is what occurs when passing the auto_ptr as function parameter. It is designed this way, it does not mean it is broken.

Comment: "You should not give `auto_ptr` as an argument to a function": rather, giving `auto_ptr` as an argument is a very effective means of saying that the function takes over all ownership of the object, and that it should not be accessed by the caller after the call.  (I use `auto_ptr` as parameter to my message passing between threads; once the originating thread has passed the object to another thread, it should no longer access it.)

Comment: @FrerichRaabe Very broken is probably the wrong term, but auto_ptr has several problems (one is the name, the other that the copy constructor implements move semantics - which is just plain wrong and an implication of the missing rvalue semantics in C++98).

Comment: @JamesKanze: You are correct, but the problem of auto_ptr as argument is, that the compiler does not make sure, that you are moving it. std::unique_ptr does not have a copy constructor, but a move constructor - so the OP's code would not compile with std::unique_ptr, he would need to surround the argument with std::move - which makes clear, that he moves the object. This is what I mean by very broken: a copy constructor that implements move semantics is semantically wrong

Comment: @MarkusPilman There are no problems giving `auto_ptr` as argument, and I'm not sure that `unique_ptr` will even work here.  The whole point _is_ that copying `auto_ptr` invalidates the original, even if it is an lvalue.  The fact that it is invalidated is a documented post-condition of the function.  (I understand your point about `std::move` documenting the intent at the call site, but it seems like a bit of overkill to me.)

Comment: @JamesKanze As you can see from the OP's code, it is at least not always overkill ;) I agree with you, that as soon as you know, that auto_ptr is a special object, it is not really a problem. But it is still something you have to care about. For all objects in the std namespace you are guaranteed, that a call by value copies the object - except for auto_ptr. The fact that copying an object does destroy the original is very counter-intuitive (unique_ptr will not compile unless you wrap it into a std::move which will invalidate the original). This is also the reason why auto_ptr is deprecated.

Comment: @MarkusPilman That `auto_ptr`'s copy semantics are somewhat surprising is certain.  On the other hand, you shouldn't be using an object without knowing its semantics; when I use `auto_ptr` in an interface, it's because I specifically want these semantics.  And there _are_ very few cases where you would want them in an interface; I think the interthread message queue is the only one I've encountered.  (For return values, it's less of an issue.)

Answer (score 1):

auto_ptr has a "magical" copy constructor that messes with the source object. By passing arguments by value to your function, you trigger the call to copy constructor, and leave the original auto_ptr in the state where it points to nothing.

Comment: Thanks, I suspected that. So I should pass by reference, but how to do it correctly with aout pointers?

Answer (score 0):

The reason that calling

```
int GetM(auto_ptr<ClassType> aM);
```

destructs the given object is that `auto_ptr` has a fairly surprising behaviour when copying objects; it not only modifies the destination object, it also modifies the *source* object. Do if you do

```
std::auto_ptr<int> y = x;  // modifies x *and* y
```

The pointer stored in `x` is *moved* to `y` (`x` is set to null).

This means that `std::auto_ptr` is very inappropriate for passing values around or storing them in containers (since containers tend to copy objects around internally). It *is* appropriate for making sure that some object gets destroyed when exiting some scope - for instance to make code exception safe. So having something like

```
void f() {
  std::auto_ptr<int> x = new int;
  ...
  // no need to delete anything, destroying 'x' will delete
}
```

Or

```
class Widget {
public:
  Widget() : m_myData( new int ) { }

private:
  Widget(const Widget &other); // disabled
  void operator=( const Widget &other ); // disabled

  std::auto_ptr<int> m_myData;
};
```

Is actually fine and can simplify code.

Having a `std::auto_ptr` means having ownership. So in your particular case, I'd suggest to adjust the `GetM` signature so that it takes a plain pointer.

Answer (score 0):

`auto_ptr` uses a little trick so that whenever you "copy" A to B, B gets the object and A is cleared. You can use this to declare ownership passing semantics very clearly (source: Scott Meyers and Andrei Alexandrescus books. Btw, if you want to know more, read Effective C++).

Of course, if possible, you should use `unique_ptr` (you can put it in vectors!) from C++0x or from Boost instead of `auto_ptr`, as `auto_ptr` is deprecated.

If you are interested in the trick details, know that there is no magic copy constructor. There is no copy constructor at all. Copy constructor takes const reference, and you would not be able to clear the copied object. So when you write

```
std::auto_ptr<A> a1(new A);
std::auto_ptr<A> a2(a1);
```

a1 is first casted to some temporary object. The cast operator takes non-const reference and clears a1. Then a2 is initialized by this temporary object.